# allow HTTP AUTHENTICATION for PHP - bitnami lampstack

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, magento2, bitnami, http-authentication

I have an amazon aws server. I have installed bitnami lampstack to run site. My php version is 7.0.18.

I want to allow the HTTP AUTHENTICATION for PHP for a payment notificaiton. My server api is apache 2.0 handler. I am not able to get an idea that how http authentication would work.

Can any one please help me that what it is and how i can enable it. By the way my site is in magento 2.

Comment: Can you tell us if you are using an extension or writing your own module, please provide more details. Additionally I suggest that you move your question to magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @lloiacono. I am implementing adyen payments. They require to send notification on url. But they asking me to allow http authentication which i don't know how it will happen for bitnami.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami Developer here,

Based on https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-create-a-password-to-protect-access-to-an-application, you should edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf/httpd-app.conf` in your instance. This is an example:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/htdocs">
  ...
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName MyAuthName
    AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/APPNAME_users"
    Require valid-user
  ...  

  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
  # Require all granted
  </IfVersion>
  ...
</Directory>
```

Another option would be editing `/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf/htaccess.conf`.

After adapting the configuration to your needs, restart Apache:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Comment: Thanks @Javier. I already resolved it and yes, your solution is correct. Can you please let me know. If i want to do it only for specific url then what change i require to do in above solution?

Comment: Thanks. The `Location` directive should do the job http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location